# Pointer to heap memory locations that store integers

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I am very confused about following question and answer:

Question:
A class called Pair has already been declared, but the constructors have not been implemented yet. Pair has two public member variables:

```
    int *pa,*pb;
```

These two "pointers to int" are intended to point to heap memory locations that store integers. The remainder of the Pair class expects the following functionality.

A single constructor Pair(int a, int b): This should set up pa and pb to point to newly allocated memory locations on the heap. The integers at those memory locations should be assigned values according to the constructor's integer arguments a and b.
A copy constructor Pair(const Pair& other): This takes as its argument a read-only reference to another Pair. It should set up the newly constructed Pair as a "deep copy," that is, it should create a new Pair that is equivalent to the other Pair based on dereferenced values but does not reuse any of the same memory locations. In other words, the copy constructor should set up its own instance's member variables pa and pb to point to newly allocated memory locations for integers on the heap; those memory locations must be new, not the same locations pointed to by the other Pair, but the integers at these new locations should be assigned values according to the integers that the other Pair is pointing to.
A destructor ~Pair() that de-allocates all of the the heap memory that had previously been allocated for this Pair's members.
The types of these member functions have already been declared in the declaration of Pair. Now you need to provide the implementation of each of these three member functions.

(Note: The function declarations shown in the code comment below do not include parameter names for the arguments. They show only the types of the arguments. This is allowed for a declaration, but when you define the implementation of those functions, you should give names to the parameters so that you can refer to them.)

Answer:

```
     /* Class Pair has already been declared
     * as shown in the following comments:
     *
     * class Pair {
      * public:
      *   int *pa,*pb;
      *   Pair(int, int);
      *   Pair(const Pair &);
      *  ~Pair();
      * };
      *
      * Implement its member functions below.
      */
      Pair::Pair(int a, int b){
        pa = new int;
        pb = new int;

        *pa = a;
        *pb = b;
      }
      Pair::Pair(const Pair & obj) {
         pa = new int;
         *pa = *(obj.pa);
         pb = new int;
         *pb = *(obj.pb);
       }
      Pair::~Pair() {
        delete pa;
        delete pb;
       }



      /* Here is a main() function you can use
       * to check your implementation of the
       * class Pair member functions.
       */

     int main() {
       Pair p(15,16);
       std::cout << "first finished"<< std::endl;
       Pair q(p);
       std::cout << "second finished"<< std::endl;
       Pair *hp = new Pair(23,42);
       std::cout << "third finished"<< std::endl;
       delete hp;

       std::cout << "If this message is printed,"
         << " at least the program hasn't crashed yet!\n"
         << "But you may want to print other diagnostic messages too." << std::endl;
       return 0;
     }
```

I was asked to create the pointer to the heap in these constructors. And the corresponding answer is:

```
    pa = new int;
    pb = new int;
```

But in my understanding, it should be:

```
    int *pa = new int;
    int *pb = new int;
```

I am very confused about this. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Unrelated: To complete the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) `Pair` should also have an assignment operator.

Comment: Unrelated: `Pair::Pair(int a, int b)` could also be implemented as `Pair::Pair(int a, int b):pa(new int(a)), pb(new int(b)){}`. This make use of the [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor). It doesn't do much in this case, but the member initializer list will save your bacon many times over when your classes get more complex. Good thing to learn early.

Answer (score 2):

`class Pair` already declares two member variables `pa` and `pb` with type `int*`.  The point of the constructor is to provide initial values for them.

Within the scope of the constructor's function body (or any non-static class member function), those member variables are accessible directly by name.  If you use `pa`, it is essentially the same as `this->pa`.  In other words, it's accessing the `pa` member of the current object which is of type `Pair`.

However, if you actually provide a type definition, it changes the meaning.  These are now new *local variables* which override the implicit names that would have otherwise referred to members of your object.

```
// These names are local variables
int *pa = new int;
int *pb = new int;
```

The problem above is two-fold.  Firstly, you did not initialize your class members.  Secondly, you are going to leak memory because when these variables go out of scope (when the function returns), you no longer have access to those pointer values and so you cannot delete them.

Comment: Thirdly, you used raw pointers instead of a smart pointer, like `std::unique_ptr`.